# Star TSP100Lan Receipt Printer + PHP + CentOS

Tags: php, vim, printing, escaping

We have a number of StarTSP100 receipt printers and can print to them fine from a browser using HTML and the [jZebra](https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/) Java Applet. Some customers, however, would like to have a printer without a physical till (when they have a large dining area and just want to print the check without going to the bar etc). To do this we are using a Star TSP100Lan printer, exactly the same a USB version we use, except for the connection.

As we're no longer communicating to the printer in a Windows environment via Java, but directly from the server (CentOS 6.4 with CUPS), the HTML is no parsed. While this is a shame, the [manual](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/Mannualfolder/comemu_starline_pm.pdf) for print shows that it can do a range formatting options which should suffice.

My editor of choice is vim and my code looks like this:

```
$ToPrint = sprintf("^[-%s^[-", 'My Text');
```

This is then sent to a known good process that that runs something similar to:

```
lpr -p star100 print.php
```

The part that looks like '^[' is the ASCII representation of what I think is the ESC (escape) code, which I make by doing CTRL+v then typing x1b, then typing -

Sadly my output does not come out underlined as expected.

My question is 2 fold:
1. Why doesn't the text underline?
2. How would I represent a more complex code, such as "ESC * r m l" (which would set the left margin)?

Thanks in advance,

James